# what is the best way to merge dictionary values based on given "key" string

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have below dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
d.Add("ship", "I");
d.Add("shep", "V");
d.Add("ssed", "X");
d.Add("aspe", "L");
```

below is the input text line:
   string line = "shep ship ship";

How can i best way to convert above line words(shep,ship and ship) to appropriate roman number from above dictionary. For above line, it should appear as VII (shep shep ship).

```
  Dictionary<string, int> dCost = new Dictionary<string, int>();
  dCost.Add("aspe aspe MaterialType1", 64);
  dCost.Add("ssed ssed MaterialType2", 5880);
```

i want to convert above dCost dictionary key `aspe aspe MaterialType1` to appropriate roman number as from first dictionary 
so, above both line should be converted to `LL MaterialType1` and other one, 'XX MaterialType2`.  it will be fine to get result on new dictionary too or just access first element of dictionary to fetch/parse to roman mapping.

**NEED: for now, i have been passing ROMAN value to convert its related value but now, i will have input as provided above in dictionary which map with ROMAN number. So, i need to fetch appropriate number based on given input and pass to API for convert roman to number.**

can any one suggest me the best approach to merge these dictionaries with its mapping value, it will be fine for linq or any approach.

Thank You

Comment: It's not clear what the second dictionary is meant to be, or where you want the results. Should they be in another dictionary?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, it will be fine on new dictionary too or just access first element of dictionary to fetch/parse to roman mapping.thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's really not particularly clear what you're after, but I suspect this would at least help:

```
public static string ReplaceAll(string text,
                                Dictionary<string, string> replacements)
{
    foreach (var pair in replacements)
    {
        text = text.Replace(pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }
    return text;
}
```

Notes:

- This won't do what you want if "shep" (etc) could appear in the real text. You may want to use regular expressions to perform replacements on word boundaries only.
- This will currently preserve the spaces in the input, so you'd end up with "L L MaterialType1" instead of "LL MaterialType1".

Comment: thanks for your comments. How i could fetch match value from dictionary for `shep ship ship` so, result should be VII (no space and value fetch from dictionary). it would be really great if found some approach through regex/linq.

Comment: updated question with some background details where i need this.

Comment: @Dhaval: It would be tricky in terms of the spaces, to be honest. If you *always* know there will be 3 leading terms, that's not too bad... but the general case is harder.

Answer (score 0):

### Simple case

If we assume that a cost key always ends with a single word (i.e. *MaterialType1*), then the last space in your key separates the text to be translated from the material type name.

In example:

> "aspe aspe MaterialType1"

To translate this string, you could use something like this code snippet.

```
foreach(var cost in dCosts)
{
    int lastSpaceIndex = cost.Key.LastIndexOf(" ");
    string materialTypeName = cost.Key.Substring(lastSpaceIndex + 1)
                                      .Trim();
    string translatedKey = cost.Key.Substring(0, lastSpaceIndex);
    foreach (var translation in d)
    {
        translatedKey = translatedKey.Replace(translation.Key, translation.Value)
                                     .Trim();
    }

    translatedKey = translatedKey.Replace(" ", string.Empty);       

    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} cost is {2}", 
                      translatedKey,
                      materialTypeName,
                      cost.Value);
}
```

### Complex case

Please, consider it as example. You can achieve the "translated" string key as follows.

```
foreach(var cost in dCosts)
{
    string translatedKey = cost.Key;
    foreach (var translation in d)
    {
        translatedKey = translatedKey.Replace(translation.Key, translation.Value)
                                     .Trim();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("{0} cost is {1}", translatedKey, cost.Value);
}
```

As @JonSkeet notes in his answer, with this code snippet you keep spaces between "translated" values, so is not really an answer to this case.

Comment: I think you want `translatedKey.Replace` rather than `cost.Key.Replace`